# ITINERARY REQUIRED TO COMPLETE TRANSACTION after PassengerDetails Request

Tags: web-services, wsdl, sabre

Using Sabre SOAP API Orchestrated Air Booking.
After SOAP EnhancedAirBook (version 3.2.0) request/result we are sending a PassengerDetails (version 3.1.0) request and we get the "**ITINERARY REQUIRED TO COMPLETE TRANSACTION**" message in results (see xmls below).
How can we get the PNR after in the PassengerDetails response?

```
<!-- 1. EnhancedAirBookRQ -->
<EnhancedAirBookRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="3.2.0">
<OTA_AirBookRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2">
<HaltOnStatus Code="UC" />
<HaltOnStatus Code="UC" />
<HaltOnStatus Code="LL" />
<HaltOnStatus Code="UL" />
<HaltOnStatus Code="UN" />
<HaltOnStatus Code="NO" />
<HaltOnStatus Code="HL" />
<OriginDestinationInformation>
  <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2015-08-08T08:40:00" DepartureDateTime="2015-08-08T05:30:00" FlightNumber="778" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="J" Status="NN">
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
    <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="778" />
    <MarriageGrp Ind="false" />
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="TLV" />
  </FlightSegment>
  <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2015-08-08T14:40:00" DepartureDateTime="2015-08-08T13:30:00" FlightNumber="423" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="J" Status="NN">
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="TXL" />
    <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="423" />
    <MarriageGrp Ind="true" />
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
  </FlightSegment>
  <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2015-08-15T18:35:00" DepartureDateTime="2015-08-15T15:25:00" FlightNumber="424" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="J" Status="NN">
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
    <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="424" />
    <MarriageGrp Ind="false" />
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="TXL" />
  </FlightSegment>
  <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2015-08-15T23:20:00" DepartureDateTime="2015-08-15T20:00:00" FlightNumber="777" NumberInParty="1" ResBookDesigCode="J" Status="NN">
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="TLV" />
    <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="777" />
    <MarriageGrp Ind="true" />
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
  </FlightSegment>
 </OriginDestinationInformation>
 <RedisplayReservation NumAttempts="5" WaitInterval="2000" />
 </OTA_AirBookRQ>
 <PostProcessing xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2">
  <RedisplayReservation WaitInterval="2000" />
 </PostProcessing>
 <PreProcessing xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2" />
```

```
<!-- 2. EnhancedAirBookRS --> 
<EnhancedAirBookRS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ApplicationResults status="Complete" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01">
  <Success timeStamp="2015-08-02T10:52:43.857+03:00" />
</ApplicationResults>
<OTA_AirBookRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2">
<OriginDestinationOption>
  <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="08-08T08:40" DepartureDateTime="08-08T05:30" eTicket="true" FlightNumber="0778" NumberInParty="001" ResBookDesigCode="J" Status="NN">
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
    <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="0778" />
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="TLV" />
  </FlightSegment>
  <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="08-08T14:40" DepartureDateTime="08-08T13:30" eTicket="true" FlightNumber="0423" NumberInParty="001" ResBookDesigCode="J" Status="NN">
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="TXL" />
    <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="0423" />
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
  </FlightSegment>
  <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="08-15T18:35" DepartureDateTime="08-15T15:25" eTicket="true" FlightNumber="0424" NumberInParty="001" ResBookDesigCode="J" Status="NN">
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
    <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="0424" />
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="TXL" />
  </FlightSegment>
  <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="08-15T23:20" DepartureDateTime="08-15T20:00" eTicket="true" FlightNumber="0777" NumberInParty="001" ResBookDesigCode="J" Status="NN">
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="TLV" />
    <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="0777" />
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
  </FlightSegment>
</OriginDestinationOption>
</OTA_AirBookRS>
<TravelItineraryReadRS xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/eab/v3_2">
<TravelItinerary>
  <CustomerInfo />
  <ItineraryInfo>
    <ReservationItems>
      <Item RPH="1">
        <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="1272" ArrivalDateTime="08-08T08:40" ConnectionInd="O" DayOfWeekInd="6" DepartureDateTime="2015-08-08T05:30" ElapsedTime="03.10" eTicket="false" FlightNumber="0778" NumberInParty="01" ResBookDesigCode="J" SegmentNumber="0001" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="SS" StopQuantity="00">
          <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
          <Equipment AirEquipType="763" />
          <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="0778" />
          <Meal Code="N" />
          <OriginLocation LocationCode="TLV" Terminal="TERMINAL 3 INTERNATIONAL" TerminalCode="3" />
          <SupplierRef ID="DCPS" />
          <UpdatedArrivalTime>08-08T08:40</UpdatedArrivalTime>
          <UpdatedDepartureTime>08-08T05:30</UpdatedDepartureTime>
        </FlightSegment>
      </Item>
      <Item RPH="2">
        <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0777" ArrivalDateTime="08-08T14:40" ConnectionInd="I" DayOfWeekInd="6" DepartureDateTime="2015-08-08T13:30" ElapsedTime="02.10" eTicket="false" FlightNumber="0423" NumberInParty="01" ResBookDesigCode="J" SegmentNumber="0002" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="SS" StopQuantity="00">
          <DestinationLocation LocationCode="TXL" />
          <Equipment AirEquipType="735" />
          <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="0423" />
          <Meal Code="N" />
          <OriginLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
          <SupplierRef ID="DCPS" />
          <UpdatedArrivalTime>08-08T14:40</UpdatedArrivalTime>
          <UpdatedDepartureTime>08-08T13:30</UpdatedDepartureTime>
        </FlightSegment>
      </Item>
      <Item RPH="3">
        <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="0777" ArrivalDateTime="08-15T18:35" ConnectionInd="O" DayOfWeekInd="6" DepartureDateTime="2015-08-15T15:25" ElapsedTime="02.10" eTicket="false" FlightNumber="0424" NumberInParty="01" ResBookDesigCode="J" SegmentNumber="0003" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="SS" StopQuantity="00">
          <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
          <Equipment AirEquipType="735" />
          <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="0424" />
          <Meal Code="N" />
          <OriginLocation LocationCode="TXL" />
          <SupplierRef ID="DCPS" />
          <UpdatedArrivalTime>08-15T18:35</UpdatedArrivalTime>
          <UpdatedDepartureTime>08-15T15:25</UpdatedDepartureTime>
        </FlightSegment>
      </Item>
      <Item RPH="4">
        <FlightSegment AirMilesFlown="1272" ArrivalDateTime="08-15T23:20" ConnectionInd="I" DayOfWeekInd="6" DepartureDateTime="2015-08-15T20:00" ElapsedTime="03.20" eTicket="false" FlightNumber="0777" NumberInParty="01" ResBookDesigCode="J" SegmentNumber="0004" SmokingAllowed="false" SpecialMeal="false" Status="SS" StopQuantity="00">
          <DestinationLocation LocationCode="TLV" Terminal="TERMINAL 3 INTERNATIONAL" TerminalCode="3" />
          <Equipment AirEquipType="763" />
          <MarketingAirline Code="PS" FlightNumber="0777" />
          <Meal Code="N" />
          <OriginLocation LocationCode="KBP" />
          <SupplierRef ID="DCPS" />
          <UpdatedArrivalTime>08-15T23:20</UpdatedArrivalTime>
          <UpdatedDepartureTime>08-15T20:00</UpdatedDepartureTime>
        </FlightSegment>
      </Item>
    </ReservationItems>
  </ItineraryInfo>
  <ItineraryRef AirExtras="false" InhibitCode="U" PartitionID="AA" PrimeHostID="1S">
    <Source PseudoCityCode="P8NG" />
  </ItineraryRef>
  <OpenReservationElements />
</TravelItinerary>
</TravelItineraryReadRS>
```

```
<!-- 3. PassengerDetailsRQ-->
<PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="3.1.1">
<PostProcessing xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_1">
<EndTransactionRQ>
  <EndTransaction Ind="true" />
  <Source ReceivedFrom="ESHET TOURS SITE" />
</EndTransactionRQ>
</PostProcessing>
<PreProcessing xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_1" />
<SpecialReqDetails xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_1">
<AddRemarkRQ>
  <RemarkInfo>
    <FOP_Remark Type="CA" />
    <Remark Code="Z" Type="Alpha-Coded">
      <Text>ID-NF</Text>
    </Remark>
  </RemarkInfo>
</AddRemarkRQ>
<SpecialServiceRQ>
  <SpecialServiceInfo>
    <SecureFlight SegmentNumber="A" SSR_Code="DOCS">
      <PersonName DateOfBirth="1990-01-01" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
        <GivenName>YARIN</GivenName>
        <Surname>LACHYNI</Surname>
      </PersonName>
    </SecureFlight>
    <Service SSR_Code="OSI">
      <PersonName NameNumber="0.0" />
      <Text>ESHET TOURS/TEL AVIV/1700700242/ESHET TOURS</Text>
      <VendorPrefs>
        <Airline Code="YY" />
      </VendorPrefs>
    </Service>
  </SpecialServiceInfo>
</SpecialServiceRQ>
</SpecialReqDetails>
<TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_1">
<AgencyInfo>
  <Address>
    <AddressLine>Eshet Tours 1700700242</AddressLine>
    <CityName>TEL AVIV</CityName>
    <CountryCode>IL</CountryCode>
    <PostalCode>67448</PostalCode>
    <StateCountyProv StateCode="TLV" />
    <StreetNmbr>NAHALAT ITSHAK 12</StreetNmbr>
  </Address>
  <Ticketing PseudoCityCode="P8NG" QueueNumber="322" ShortText="TEST Short Text" TicketType="7T-A" />
</AgencyInfo>
<CustomerInfo>
    <ContactNumbers>
    <ContactNumber NameNumber="1.1" Phone="972-3-7749965" PhoneUseType="H" />
  </ContactNumbers>
  <PersonName Infant="false" NameNumber="1.1" NameReference="DOB01JAN90" PassengerType="ADT">
    <GivenName>YARIN</GivenName>
    <Surname>LACHYNI</Surname>
  </PersonName>
</CustomerInfo>
</TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
```

```
<!-- 4. PassengerDetailsRS-->
<PassengerDetailsRS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ApplicationResults status="Complete" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01">
   <Success timeStamp="2015-08-02T10:52:45.451+03:00" />
   <Warning type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2015-08-02T10:52:45.45+03:00">
    <SystemSpecificResults>
      <Message code="WARN.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE">ITINERARY REQUIRED TO COMPLETE TRANSACTION</Message>
    </SystemSpecificResults>
   </Warning>
  </ApplicationResults>
</PassengerDetailsRS>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sabre Support, 
the problem was sending a SabreCommandLLS call with parameter HCmd=IR
after the EnhancedAirBook call. 
The SabreCommandLLS call with parameter HCmd=IR ignores the unsaved pervious steps.
That is why the PassengerDetails call did not find any itinerary for creating the PNR.

Comment: can you please explain what you did to solve this issue?

Comment: Im also facing the same issue, please let me know

Comment: In our flow we removed the step: SabreCommandLLS call with parameter HCmd=IR that was after the EnhancedAirBook step.
If you are doing the SabreCommandLLS (HCmd=IR) step after the EnhancedAirBook step then removi it.